# Blank page after configuring ec2 instance and installing tomcat7

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I created a new AWS account and started a new tier 2 instance. So I did following things afterward :

1. Created elastic IP and associated it with the instance.
2. Configured the inbound security groups for http, https and custom TCP rule:8080
3. Installed tomcat7 using "sudo yum install tomcat7"
4. Started tomcat using "sudo service tomcat7 start"

Finally, i tried to check the tomcat, by hitting http://elastic-ip:8080 from the browser but a blank page comes up.
I guess this is a 404 error. Please help me which part have i missed.

Comment: Now, i have put up a sample project in webapps folder and i am able to hit the project index page. But i still get a blank page when i hit : http://elastic-ip:8080

Comment: What does `netstat -an` show on that instance?

Comment: curl to the index to see what the real response value is. Don't assume a blank page means 404.